# Database design advice on a marksheet schema

Tags: database-design

I am not sure whether this type of question is allowed here, but seeing other questions, i think it is.

I am doing a database design of processing exam marks. There is a marksheet for each of the answersheet. Marksheet is identified by reference of answer sheet. Each answer sheet is evaluated by 2 or more examiner.

I want to store the marks for each questions. So, if a question paper has 8 questions, there should be 8 entry for marks, some of which can be blank depending on whether the student has answered that question or something.

And there is a `paper code` associated with each answer sheet, which is unique for a given exam.

This is my `AnswerSheet` Table

```
Id (Primary Key)
Exam_ID (foreign key to exam table)
Paper Code (manually given for each paper, unique for a single exam)
```

**Note that, by `exam` I am referring to a single course exam, not whole set of exams.**

Here is my Marksheet table:

```
Id (Primary key)
Answer_sheet_id (foriegn key to the answer sheet table)
Examiner_ID (to identify the teacher evaluated this sheet)
Mark on Question 1
.
.
Mark on Question 8
```

Here, you see that I am hardcoding the question 1 to 8 in the database, which I think a bad design. My logic is that, It's very unlikely to change the no of questions in an exam in future. But, It's not absolutely guranteed.

I am seeking other alternative/better design for this problem?

Comment: This sounds very much like this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142282/database-design-for-an-exam

Answer (score 1):

There should be questions table that contain all questions with unique ID to each question. A new table reference AnswerSheet table Id and questions id  should be there.